# How can I write Java CriteriaBuilder for the query given below

Tags: java

How can I write the query in Java CriteriaBuilder?

```
SELECT c FROM UserTransaction c WHERE  c.status in ('M', 'P') AND
instr(c.idNumber,:idNum) > 0 order by c.userI
```

Note: idNum is a variable

Please see what I started writing. But I cannot get it compiled.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
ParameterExpression<String> idnumParameter = cb.parameter(String.class, idNum);
ParameterExpression<Integer> numberParameter = cb.parameter(Integer.class)       

CriteriaQuery<UserTransaction > cq = cb.createQuery(UserTransaction .class);
Root<UsasTransaction> postRoot = cq.from(UserTransaction .class);

Predicate predicateInM    = cb.equal(postRoot.get("status"),"M");
Predicate predicateInP    = cb.equal(postRoot.get("status"),"P");
Predicate predicateStatus = cb.or(predicateInM, predicateInP);

Predicate predicateInstr  = (Predicate) cb.function("INSTR", Boolean.class, postRoot.get("idNumber"), idnumParameter );
Predicate predicateGt     = cb.gt(predicateInstr, 0);
```

Comment: If you are free to do so take a look a JOOQ. Less pain more SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Firstly, when posting a question, please make sure that you supply all the information pertinent to the question.  Terms like "I cannot get it compiled"  are just too vague;  as you know, in programming details are important, so we'd need to more detailed information in order to help you like : Is there a compilation error?  If so, what is the error message, and on what line?  etc, etc.

Still, looking at the code, there are a few things :

- UsasTransaction - I assume that's just a typo
- Predicate.
  Beware that there are multiple different classes in different packages called "Predicate", and your IDE may have suggested the wrong one by default, so you need to make sure you import the right one.
- cb.function - that returns an Expression, not a Predicate

Putting those together, try the following :

```
    import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;

    String idNumParamName = "idnum";
    String idNumParamValue = "ABC123";

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    ParameterExpression<String> idnumParameter = cb.parameter(String.class, idNumParamName);
    ParameterExpression<Integer> numberParameter = cb.parameter(Integer.class) ;      

    CriteriaQuery<UserTransaction > cq = cb.createQuery(UserTransaction .class);
    Root<UserTransaction> postRoot = cq.from(UserTransaction .class);

    Predicate predicateInM    = cb.equal(postRoot.get("status"),"M");
    Predicate predicateInP    = cb.equal(postRoot.get("status"),"P");
    Predicate predicateStatus = cb.or(predicateInM, predicateInP);

    Expression<Integer> expressionInstr  = cb.function("INSTR", Integer.class, postRoot.get("idNumber"), idnumParameter );
    Predicate predicateGt     = cb.gt(expressionInstr, 0);

    cq.select(postRoot).where(cb.and(predicateStatus, predicateGt));

    UserTransactions = em.createQuery(cq).setParameter(idNumParamName, idNumParamValue).getResultList();
```

Comment: Well as I have said, my original query is:

Comment: My original query is: SELECT c FROM UserTransaction c WHERE  c.status in ('M', 'P') AND instr(c.idNumber,:idNum) > 0 order by c.userId.  How do I add the instr(c.idNumber,:idNum) > 0  using CriteriaBuilder. That was the problem I had.

Comment: Hence my comment that just saying "not compiling" is not enough.  So looking at that expression, the INSTR function returns an integer position, so you need to pass that type to the cb.function.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: As  long as the query has only cq.select(postRoot).where(predicateStatus);  no error. But moment I AND with the second criteria predicateGt this error pops up. cq.select(postRoot).where(cb.and(predicateStatus,predicateGt));

Comment: Great - so we've got past the compiler errors, and are attempting to run it.  So the problem now is to be aware that with the idNum parameter, there are two Strings - the parameter name (the ":idNum") and the Value you want it to use on the particular time you run the query.  You've specified the first, but the error is saying that you haven't specified the second, so I've added this to the code.  BTW, generally don't add "answers" to your own questions, since lots of people would skip even looking at questions with multiple answers.  Much better to edit the question instead :)